# Click event not working on a tag loaded by Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I load a block of HTML stored within a XML file by Ajax and this HTML contains a a tag on which the click event is expected to do something.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async:false,
            url: "/js/content/cookiesBandeauContent.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                    // Parse the xml file and get data
                   //var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                    $xml = $(xml);

                   $("body").prepend($xml.find(sLang+" paragraphContent").text());

            }
        });
```

Basically the HTML loaded looks like this:

```
<div id='background_cookies'>
      <div id='cookies'>
           <p class='cookies'>XXXXXXXX<a class='cookiesPolicy' href='/cookies_policy/cookies_policy.aspx' target='_blank'>Politique de Cookies</a>.<br>
            XXXX<a class='cookiesSettings' href='/cookies_settings/cookies_settings.aspx' target='_blank'>Paramètres des Cookies</a>.
           </p>
            <a class='cookies_continue' href='#'>Continuer</a>
       </div>
</div>
```

The click event is declared in the document ready:

```
$("div#cookies a.cookies_continue").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $("div#cookies").fadeOut();
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is this AJAX request only going to be called once? I ask because the content loaded contains IDs that, if prepended more than once, will not be valid as IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to bind the event after you append the html after the ajax call. If you append something dynamically, you need to bind the event after you append it.

```
function BindEventCookie() {
    $("div#cookies a.cookies_continue").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $("div#cookies").fadeOut();
    });
}

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        url: "/js/content/cookiesBandeauContent.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
                // Parse the xml file and get data
               //var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                $xml = $(xml);

               $("body").prepend($xml.find(sLang+" paragraphContent").text());
               BindEventCookie();

        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

I make a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/e42d703o/

Comment: I make a fiddle to illustrate my point. It's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

in the success function

```
      success: function (xml) {
                // Parse the xml file and get data
               //var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                $xml = $(xml);

               $("body").prepend($xml.find(sLang+" paragraphContent").text());

        }
```

add the handler with the "on" jquery function

```
$("div#cookies a.cookies_continue").on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $("div#cookies").fadeOut();
});
```

which is more functional than the simple click handler, as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("div#cookies").on('click','a.cookies_continue', function(e) {
        $("div#cookies").fadeOut();
        return false;
    });
```